# Python how do I break out of blocking generator that is waiting for server response?

Tags: python, generator, google-cloud-speech

So I have this code that would take user speech and transcribe it into text using Google Cloud Speech API. It is written based on this example from Google: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_streaming_mic.py

I wanted to add an error handler that would stop the transcription process whenever there's an internet connection problem. I create a connection monitor thread that check internet connection every few seconds and will set a flag `isConnectionError = True`.

I manage to stop the audio recording generator process but I can't stop another generator process that block and waits for server to send response message:

```
def listen_print_loop(responses):

"""Iterates through server responses and prints them.
The responses passed is a generator that will block until a response
is provided by the server.
Each response may contain multiple results, and each result may contain
multiple alternatives; for details, see <url removed>.  Here we
print only the transcription for the top alternative of the top result.
In this case, responses are provided for interim results as well. If the
response is an interim one, print a line feed at the end of it, to allow
the next result to overwrite it, until the response is a final one. For the
final one, print a newline to preserve the finalized transcription.
"""
num_chars_printed = 0
for response in responses:
    if not response.results:
        continue

    # The `results` list is consecutive. For streaming, we only care about
    # the first result being considered, since once it's `is_final`, it
    # moves on to considering the next utterance.
    result = response.results[0]
    if not result.alternatives:
        continue

    # Display the transcription of the top alternative.
    transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript

    # Display interim results, but with a carriage return at the end of the
    # line, so subsequent lines will overwrite them.
    #
    # If the previous result was longer than this one, we need to print
    # some extra spaces to overwrite the previous result
    overwrite_chars = ' ' * (num_chars_printed - len(transcript))

    if not result.is_final:
        sys.stdout.write(transcript + overwrite_chars + '\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()

        num_chars_printed = len(transcript)

    else:
        print(transcript + overwrite_chars)

        # Exit recognition if any of the transcribed phrases could be
        # one of our keywords.
        if re.search(r'\b(exit|quit)\b', transcript, re.I):
            print('Exiting..')
            break

        num_chars_printed = 0
```

Comment: It will have to run in a different thread, so that thread blocks. I'd suggest it puts responses on a queue which you can check/pop in a non-blocking manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Kenny, I just run the generator in a separate thread. Works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

We achieved the same through websockets on listeners and emitters for connection where Speech-to-text hapens from web page to Java service